# No single shortcut to go to end of file

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, iterm, textedit

I'm new to Mac (10.15.5) and so far figuring out shortcuts has not been a smooth journey. Usually on Windows I would use these -

```
Home - Beginning of a line
End - End of line
Ctrl + Home - Beginning of file
Ctrl + End - End of file
```

and these work for any text editor or application like a terminal. On Mac,

```
Command + Left arrow - Beginning of line in TextEdit (Fn + left does page up I think)
Fn + Left Arrow - Beginning of line in iTerm (Command + left does nothing)
```

How do I set universal shortcuts to go to beginning/end of a line/file that works in all apps?

Answer (score 5):

On my Mac, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> ("command up arrow") takes me to the top of a file/document/webpage. Same sequence with "Down arrow" takes me to the bottom of a file/document/webpage.

If that doesn't work for you, let us know & we'll try to help further.

For future reference, [Apple has a list of shortcuts on their support website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236). It also includes links to app-specific shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

Fn + Cmd + right arrow will take to End of file (document).

Fn + Right arrow key is basically home key. So if you add cmd (control) key, it'll replicate the Ctrl + Home on windows.

I also did remapping of Ctrl and Cmd key on Macbook to be line with Windows laptop.

Answer (score 1):

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 for a full list. <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> (nearly) always takes you to the beginning of the line.